# How yongnuo speedlite 685 for Canon can flash using an external battery, it's PB3000II?

Tags: battery, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, external

I have an external speedlite battery(PB3000II) connected to a Yongnuo 685 for Canon, but it doesn't function... What can I do to make it work? It's something about menu configuration? The battery works for Canon Speedlite 580, but not for this Yongnuo 685...

Comment: Does the YN685 work when using internal batteries? Do you have freshly charged internal batteries in the YN685 when attempting to use it with the external battery?

Answer (score 1):

When operating the YN685 with an external battery pack you still need to have internal batteries installed in the YN685 to power the logic circuits of the flash. The external battery will only power the capacitor. There is an option in the YN685's menu as to whether or not to use the internal batteries along with the external to charge the capacitor or whether to use the internal batteries only to power the command system of the flash. There is no option to power the entire flash via the external battery pack. You must have batteries with enough charge to operate the "brain" of the flash installed internally or the flash will not work, even when an external battery pack is connected.

Comment: Thank you! That situation doesn't happend with the speedlite Canon I have EX580, I use low alcaline batteries in it and works normal without any notification of low batteries. I thought that the external battery I have (PB3000II) were not compatible with that Yongnuo model. Thanks again!